# How to derive ${ A \vdash C }$ from ${A \lor B \vdash C}$ in the sequent calculus LK?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, proof-theory, formal-proofs, sequent-calculus

How to derive ${ A  \vdash C }$ from ${A \lor B \vdash C}$ in the sequent calculus LK? It seems obvious that if ${A \lor B \vdash C}$  is true, then ${ A  \vdash C }$ is true.
There are rules

$\cfrac {\qquad A, \ \Gamma \ \rightarrow \ \Delta }{\ A \land B, \ \Gamma \ \rightarrow \ \Delta \ }$, $\cfrac {\qquad B, \ \Gamma \ \rightarrow \ \Delta}{\ A \land B, \ \Gamma \ \rightarrow \ \Delta \ }$ $\cfrac {\Gamma \ \rightarrow \ \Delta, \ A \qquad \Gamma \ \rightarrow \ \Delta, \ B}{\ \qquad \ \Gamma \ \rightarrow \ \Delta, \ A\land B \ }$
$\cfrac {A, \ \Gamma \ \rightarrow \ \Delta \qquad B, \ \Gamma \ \rightarrow \ \Delta \ }{\ A \lor B, \ \Gamma \ \rightarrow \ \Delta \ \qquad}$, but they cannot be used here.

Answer (score 2):

From axiom and $\lor$-r:
$\cfrac { \ A \vdash A}{\ A \vdash A \lor B }$
Assumption:
$A \lor B \vdash C$.
Then apply Cut to get $A\vdash C$.

Without $\text {Cut}$ [*and without proper tree formatting*...]:

1. right branch:

$\cfrac { \ C \vdash C }{\ A, C \vdash C }$, by Ax and Weak, then:

$C \vdash A \supset C$, by $\supset \text {-r}$.

2. left branch:

$\cfrac { \ A \vdash A }{\ A \vdash A, C }$, by Ax and Weak, then:

$A \vdash A \lor B, C$, by $\lor \text {-r}$, then:

$\vdash A \lor B, A \supset C$, by $\supset \text {-r}$.

Finally:

> $\cfrac { \vdash A \lor B, A \supset C \qquad C \vdash A \supset C }{ A \lor B \supset C \vdash A \supset C }$, by $\supset \text {-l}$.

Finally:

> > $\vdash (A \lor B \supset C) \supset (A \supset C)$, by $\supset \text {-r}$.

Comment: Thank you. How about Cut-elimination theorem? Doesn't it say that it can be derived without using Cut-rule? Sorry, maybe this theorem has nothing to do with it and I just confuse the question by mentioning it. But I've seen in some books lists of rules of sequent calculus where no Cut-rule was. And I wonder how they suppose to derive $A \rightarrow C$ from $A \lor B \rightarrow C$.

Comment: It means that we can avoid using Cut only when the derivation is from the empty set (so we have the tautology as a result), but not when we use derivation to prove that $S \vDash s$, where $S$ is a set of sequents, $s$ is a sequent?

Comment: @JuljaMuvv - Seq calculus proves *sequents*. We can always conjoin a finite set $S$ of fomulas into a single formula.

Comment: Let  $p$, $q$, $r$ be variables. As you show in the first edit of the answer, we can derive  ${ p \vdash r }$ from ${p \lor q \vdash r}$  using Cut. But in the new answer you derive ${\vdash (p \lor q \rightarrow r}) \rightarrow ({ p \rightarrow r } )$, not ${ p \vdash r }$ from ${p \lor q \vdash r}$. It's not the same problem. I try to understand if we can exactly derive  ${ p \vdash r }$ from ${p \lor q \vdash r}$  without Cut, like you did it with Cut. And if we can't, why not.

Comment: @JuljaMuvv - I think not, in the form you have written it. Sequent calculus proves *sequents* and by soundness to be provable a sequent must be a tautology: $p \to r$ is not. Having said that, **all** rules - except Cut - add connectives and no rule remove it: so, how the "unpack" $p \lor q$ ?